# PLS/QL : Nasty cursor error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor

I need a hand for a PL/SQL. Indeed, i can't figure out why Oracle doesn't want to accept this code :

```
set serveroutput on;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE route (gagnant VARCHAR2) IS

CURSOR perdants IS SELECT NPerdant FROM RENCONTRE WHERE NGagnant = gagnant;

BEGIN
        FOR perdant IN perdants
        LOOP
                dbms.output.put_line(gagnant || ' bats ' || perdants.nperdant);
                route (perdants.nperdant);
        END LOOP;
END;
/
```

This is the result of the show errors command :

```
LINE/COL     ERROR
10/17    PL/SQL: Statement ignored
10/70    PLS-00225: référence de sous-programme ou de curseur 'PERDANTS' e st hors étendue
11/17    PL/SQL: Statement ignored
11/33    PLS-00225: référence de sous-programme ou de curseur 'PERDANTS' e st hors étendue
```

So it tells me that it can't acces the `perdants` cursor because of a range problem. 
But I can't see why.

Comment: `dbms.output.put_line(gagnant....` where did `gagnant` come from? Its not a row in the `CURSOR` query, neither is it a variable. Is it just a string? If so then it should be `'gagnant bats'||...`

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot the name of the input parameter...

Comment: `(gagnant VARCHAR2 (30))` should be `(gagnant VARCHAR2)`. If you don't specify the parameter would be default `IN` parameter or else you need to specify `IN OUT` or `OUT`, like `(gagnant IN OUT VARCHAR2)`.

Comment: Also, its not `range` problem, its complaining that either a variable or cursor is out of scope of the `procedure`.

Comment: All right, I did fogot that too, but it seems to not be the source of my range problem --"

Comment: Yet, i do have the two same error messages even if i put (gagnant VARCHAR2) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problematic places:

First:

```
FOR perdant IN perdants
LOOP
   dbms.output.put_line(gagnant || ' bats ' || perdants.nperdant);
    route (perdants.nperdant);
END LOOP;
```

Your loop variable is `perdant` not `perdants`, so you should rewrite `perdants.nperdant` as
`perdant.nperdant`.

Second:

```
dbms.output.put_line(...);
```

The package name is `dbms_output`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `perdant.nperdant` (without the `s`) instead of `perdants.nperdant`.  Otherwise you're not using the loop variable `perdant`.